# why is some strange character in NSDate string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using below code to get date time. I will post them to server

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

In server, I found there several log has strange data. it is encoded as `"date": "\u0662\u0660\u0661\u0666-\u0660\u0664-\u0661\u0660 \u0661\u0668:\u0665\u0669:\u0664\u0663"`

I found them show as `٢٠١٦-٠٤-١٠ ١٨:٥٩:٤٣` in UTF16, what is the problem, it seems date format is correct, but why `year-month-day hour:minitue:seconds` become invalid. Thanks~

Comment: It's certainly not related to Swift date formatting. Check how the data is sent  to and processed on the server.

Comment: server just saved client send data, and most of data is correct, and client is also just http post data, and now I do not have client environment, so do not know what client sent.

Comment: @JerryYYRain you have pretty much answered your own _"question"_ in your OP... what actually are you looking for?

Comment: how can I know its real data, ( non-arabic digits), and if I want to in any locale, the date can be digit, how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the locale on the formatter:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

`en_US_POSIX` is a standardized locale that will never change (even if the US were to change how it encodes things).

As A-Live notes, these are valid digits and valid dates. They're just not Western Arabic digits (0123456789). They're Eastern Arabic digits (٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩). `stringFromDate()` uses the locale from the formatter. If you don't set one, it uses the system locale. If you want a particular one, set it.

See [QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

These are totally valid year, month, day, etc: based on your code we can see that you've decided to accept the values of any locale, including non-arabic digits.

Comment: yes, my app will run all locale, so I want to know what this local is, and how can I know its real data, ( non-arabic digits), and if I want to in any locale, the date can be digit, how should I do?

Comment: You must never limit the locales the app can be launched at, what I was saying is that you are not **properly** supporting all the locales as you should have done with such locale-dependent interfaces. I don't know which locale that is, perhaps you can find the locales that use such digits yourself. If you are not sure those are digits, again - you can always look it up. As for how everyone avoids the problem, the dates are normally sent not as formatted text but as timestamps.